# How to get result from response inside method?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I am new android developer, how can I get result form this snippet, what way does exist, because it doesn't return anything, because of I'm adding element inside onResponse, but using only kotlin module:

```kotlin
private fun foo(list: ArrayList<CurrencyModel> = ArrayList()): ArrayList<CurrencyModel> {

        val request = Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL_YESTERDAY).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                val data = Gson().fromJson(body, Currencies::class.java)
                list.add(CurrencyModel("USD", data.rates.USD, 0.0))
                list.add(CurrencyModel("SEK", data.rates.SEK, 0.0))
                list.add(CurrencyModel("EUR", data.rates.EUR, 0.0))
            }
        })
        return list
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't return the result of an asynchronous call from the function that calls it, because the result comes some time in the future, after this function has already returned. You can either make this into a suspend function and call it from a coroutine, or you can give this function a callback parameter that will be called in `onResponse`, and your code that calls this function can respond to the result in the callback.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for answer. Could you show examlpe? that will be cool

Comment: I feel like I've answered this question on here before, but I can't find it. Just a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your function a callback parameter that's called when the response is receieved. And you shouldn't have an input list in this case, because if you have multiple sources modifying it at unpredictable future moments, it will be difficult to track.

The function can look like this:

```
private fun getCurrencyModels(callback: (ArrayList<CurrencyModel>) {

    val request = Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL_YESTERDAY).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body?.string()
            val data = Gson().fromJson(body, Currencies::class.java)
            val list = arrayListOf(
                CurrencyModel("USD", data.rates.USD, 0.0)),
                CurrencyModel("SEK", data.rates.SEK, 0.0)),
                CurrencyModel("EUR", data.rates.EUR, 0.0))
            )
            callback(list)
        }
    })
}
```

And then to use it:

```
getCurrencyModels { modelsList ->
    // do something with modelsList when it arrives
}
```

An alternative is to use coroutines, which allow you to do asynchronous actions without callbacks. Someone has already created a library that lets you use OkHttp requests in coroutines [here](https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp). You could write your function as a suspend function like this:

```
private suspend fun getCurrencyModels(): ArrayList<CurrencyModel> {

    val request = Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL_YESTERDAY).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val response = client.newCall(request).await()
    val body = response.body?.string()
    val data = Gson().fromJson(body, Currencies::class.java)
    return arrayListOf(
        CurrencyModel("USD", data.rates.USD, 0.0)),
        CurrencyModel("SEK", data.rates.SEK, 0.0)),
        CurrencyModel("EUR", data.rates.EUR, 0.0))
    )
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        val currencyModels = getCurrencyModels()
        // do something with currencyModels
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // request failed
    }
}
```

Coroutines make it really easy to avoid leaking memory when your asynchronous calls outlive your Activity or Fragment. In this case, if your Activity closes while the request is going, it will be cancelled automatically and references to your Activity will be removed so the garbage collector can release your Activity.

Comment: I try to use second variant, but await()  glows red :(

Comment: implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'

Comment: You also need the third party library I mentioned `implementation 'ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-okhttp:1.0'`

Comment: my bad, I am trying, boss

Comment: I should use it -lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        val currencyModels = getCurrencyModels()
        // do something with currencyModels
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // request failed
    }
}
in MainActivity(), because it glows red, probably I forget some implementation...

Comment: right this lifecycleScope, I wrote it inside activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val currencyModels = getLastDayCurrencyExchangeRate()
                // do something with currencyModels
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // request failed
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Is the import missing at the top of the file? `import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope` Usually when you use extension functions/properties, you have to import them. You can hover over the red text and press Alt+Enter to get the option to automatically import it.

Comment: woooow, boss, You saved my life! Thank you for answering and explaining. 100/5 stars.

Answer (score 0):

The [onResponse](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-callback/on-response/)() function is only called when the HTTP response is successfully returned by the remote server. Since this response doesn't happen immediately, you can't use the result in your code immediately. What you could do is use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) variable and add the values to that variable in onResponse(). Something like:

```
private fun foo(list: ArrayList<CurrencyModel> = ArrayList()) {

val request = Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL_YESTERDAY).build()

val client = OkHttpClient()
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        val body = response.body?.string()
        val data = Gson().fromJson(body, Currencies::class.java)
        val list: ArrayList<CurrencyModel> = arrayListOf()
        list.add(CurrencyModel("USD", data.rates.USD, 0.0))
        list.add(CurrencyModel("SEK", data.rates.SEK, 0.0))
        list.add(CurrencyModel("EUR", data.rates.EUR, 0.0))
        viewModel.list.postValue(list)
    }
})
```

}